# What is key file format for JSch?

Tags: java, jsch, private-key

JSch has a method `addIdentity(String prvkey, String passphrase)`, where prvkey is private key file. In which format it should be?

I have keys for Putty, OpenSSH and SSHCom.

Answer (score 0):

The file that you use for ssh is used in Jcsh